# Python, get neighboring objects on an axis

Tags: scripting, objects

I'm trying to use python to loop through objects in a specific way.

I have a grid of objects, evenly spaced apart:

[image]

I wan't to loop through them, to make changes. starting form the upper left, going row > column. I need the value of the row and column, as well as access to any object at any coridantes. I'm thinking that this would best be achieved by a 2D array [row][column], containing the objects.

pseudo-code:

```
for rows of objecs
    for objects in line with current row head //rowhead= left most object in the row
         //Do stuff
```

**For testing:**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did not test this yet:

```
import bpy

COL_COUNT =  8 # number of columns
ROW_COUNT = 12 # number of rows

objects = bpy.data.groups['group_name'].objects[:]

# no cmp function
# use round to circumvent floating point precision errors
key_x = lambda o: round(o.location.x, 2)
key_y = lambda o: round(o.location.y, 2)

objects.sort(key=key_y, reversed=True) # from top to bottom
objects.sort(key=key_x)

for i, obj in enumerate(objects):
    col = i  % COL_COUNT
    row = i // COL_COUNT

    #do something with obj
```

See [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) from the official documetation for more information. The [most relevant part](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) is:

> Sorts are guaranteed to be stable. That means that when multiple records have the same key, their original order is preserved.

To retrieve the object for a given row and column calculate the index:

```
index = row * COL_COUNT + col
obj = objects[index]
```

I.e. for `ROW_COUNT = 2` and `COL_COUNT = 4` the objects are tagged like this:

```
0 1 2 3 
4 5 6 7
```

For the second row and the third column the index is 1 * 4 + 2 = 6. (zero based indices!)

Comment: Testing now... :D

Comment: Ah, yes. It sorts objects, not vectors, so i added `o.location.y`

Comment: How would I access somthing, say one row up and 3 to the left?, inside the loop

Comment: You can build a nested list / array or calculate the index. The index should be `row * COL_COUNT + col` (starting with index 0)

Comment: I'm still confused, could you add that in a bit more detail to the answer?

Comment: Final point, which access it up and which is left and right, in the .blend file, z was up and y was left and right, what is it in your script?

Comment: for the blend file you would probably use key_z instead of key_y and key_y instead of key_x